# Disable double click select

Tags: css, angularjs

I use below css :

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

to disable the selection of text. But how can I modify so that the text can be selected but when user double clicks text it is not selected ?

Specifically would like to disable on `ngDblclick`

Comment: So you want to have an input with text in it that the user cannot select until the input is double clicked? Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @BradEvans user can select text but if user double clicks on text then the selection is disabled, currently if double click on text then that text ro text area is selected. Instead when user double clicks on text , the text is not selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function for 'ng-dblclick'

```
$scope.clearSelection = function () {
    if ($window.getSelection) $window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if ($document[0].selection) $document[0].selection.empty();
};
```

inject appropriate services.

Comment: what does $document[0].selection return ? Any selected text ?

Comment: it is an object with methods and properties. if I'm not mistaken document.selection works for IE < 9.